# Use Templating on JavaScript Files

Tags: javascript, node.js, templating

I'm in the most interesting position where I would like to template my JavaScript files server-side to include and remove certain parts based on an object.  Given an object like so:

```
var obj = {
    "includeA": true,
    "includeB": false,
    "includeC": true
}
```

I would like the ability to include/exclude certain parts of said JS file.  For example:

```
if (obj.includeA) {
    // This is some code from A
}

if (obj.includeB) {
   // This is some code from B
}
```

Would produce either a string or a file that looks like:

```
// This is some code from A
```

I've looked into some basic options, one of the foremost ideas that came to mind was to simply use `if` statements in JS.  This code however looks rather terrible, and considering there will be upto 1,000 lines of this,  not suitable at all:

```
var string = ""

if (obj.includeA) {
    string += "This is one line \n"
    string += "This is another line \n"
}
// etc.
```

This produces the right output, but the repetitiveness of the `string +=` makes me detest it.  I then decided to package it up into a function:

```
var string = ""

function call(line) {
    string += line + "\n"

if (obj.includeA) {
    call("This is one line")
    call"This is another line)
}
// etc.
```

But that seems only slightly better.  Is there any sort of templating engine (imagining something similar to Jade), that allows templating of text blocks like this?

Comment: I highly doubt this. You are already spending time as is appending code to a separate file repeatedly on every runtime. Just break your source into components/files. Finally call them when needed. If you do it right, there is little to no code repetition.

Comment: My interest is not on run time, in this use it doesn't have to be efficient at all.  I am literally purely interested in how it looks.  The issue I'm getting with splitting my source into files though is that it can look like: `includeA includeB includeC includeA includeC include B` in a way that cannot be rearranged.  Splitting it into files would require hundreds of seperate files for each section. @Quirk

Comment: Maybe this satisfies your needs: https://github.com/estools/estemplate

Comment: @Quirk That seems perfect in it's templating, but it seems to include no conditionals?  Unless I'm missing something really obvious.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't. My bad. That project was the closest something I could find related to your needs. You could resort to using conditionals as before, at which point the advantages from the source maps are minimal.

Comment: Indeed, I think I may have to go with your first suggestion unless someone comes up with another bright idea. Thanks so much for your help @Quirk